# Sub-images schema with two rows

Tags: graphics, subfloats

I would like to show inside my doc sub-images with the following schema:

[image: schema]

How can I do that?
Regards, vi.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possibility using `\subcaptionbox` from the `subcaption` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\subcaptionbox{}{\includegraphics[height=4cm]{example-image-a}}\hfill
\subcaptionbox{}{\includegraphics[height=4cm]{example-image-b}}\par
\subcaptionbox{}{\includegraphics[width=.8\textwidth,height=3cm]{example-image-c}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Add

```
\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=brace}
```

if you only want a right parenthesis for the label.

In a comment it was requested to do the same using `subfig` instead of `subcaption`; here's how:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[height=4cm]{example-image-a}}\hfill
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[height=4cm]{example-image-b}}\par
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=.8\textwidth,height=3cm]{example-image-c}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is it possible to use `subfig` package instead of `subcaption`?

Comment: @vdenotaris sure! I'll update the answer.

Comment: @vdenotaris answer updated.